# Reflection - getting variables from a class

Tags: java, class, reflection, get

AExampleTestClass.java only contains `public String setence = "false";`

In the class i am running there are several methods:

getPath(name) - gets the path of the file name given

getVariableNames(File) - which gets the variables within the file given
and

change(classname,var,to) - which is meant to replace the variable in the class name given with String "to".

now when i run `getPath("AExampleTestClass")`

it returns the correct path

`C:\Users\..\test\AExampleTestClass.java`

but when i run

`getPath("AExampleTestClass").getClass()`

it returns

`class java.lang.String`

so therefore when i use getVariables... it returns the variables in java.lang.String not in AExampleTestClass.java

what can i use to access a variable of unknown name from a class of an unknown name (class + variable names are strings)?

Answer (score 0):

`getClass()` returns the class of the object you're calling it on.
When you call it on a `String`, it always returns `String.class`.

You want `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass(...)`

Comment: what do i put in the loadClass(String) cause using a correct path just gets a class not found exception?

Comment: @user2871826: To load from a filepath, I believe you need a `URLClassLoader`.

Comment: Ive looked into it and nothing seems to be of relevance, i dont see why its so hard to use "foo f = new foo(); f.var = 4;" but just with variables as class name and variable name :3

Answer (score 0):

As `getPath` returns a `String`, the method invokes the `getClass` method for that string.

Your code is the same as doing this:

```
String path = getPath("AExampleTestClass");  // returns a String with the path
path.getClass();   // returns String.class as expected
```